# how to change folder names in Windows 10 start menu

Tags: windows-10, start-menu

Is there a way to change the names of start menu folders in Windows 10?

For example rename "windows accessories" to "accessories"?

All I found so far is how to change single programs, folders etc.

Even removing unneccesary apps like x-box was much more complicated than  expected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your start menu is a composite of your personal and the *All Users* start menus These are in `%USERPROFILEFILE%\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu` and `%ALLUSERSPROFILE%\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu`. In particular, `Windows Accessories` is in *All Users*.

If you navigate to these directories in `cmd`, you can simply rename the directories, but in *All Users* you need to note:-

- The new names will apply to every user who logs in.
- You'll need administrative permissions to make changes.
- Windows Updates are likely to restore the old names.

Likewise, old names in your personal or the *All Users* start menu may also be restored by application software updates, and uninstalling will not remove the renamed start menu entries.